# How Can I Represent Postgresql Intervals in Ruby On Rails fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, minitest

I'm trying to create fixtures for my tests and I have an [“Interval”](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_postgresql.html#interval) field in the one of my models.

How can I represent this “interval” field in my fixtures file?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ERB syntax in your fixtures files

For example you have `events` table with `duration` column type `interval`

In console you can create new record as

```
Event.create(duration: 2.days)
```

And in `events.yml` fixtures as

```
two_days:
  duration: <%= 2.days %>

three_days:
  duration: <%= 3.days %>
```